# Formatting errors when objects or strings in Winston

Tags: node.js, winston, loggly

I have an issue that my errors show up different, as some are a String, others are objects. When they are an object the whole "msg" is what I need outputted, but when it just a string, then just outputting the string is fine. if I remove my printf line, it prints fine, but I need the printf because I want to truncate the logs outputted to first 200 characters (this part hasn't been added yet, I want to get the correct output first).

As soon as I add the printf it starts treating the errors differently.

If there is an easier way to truncate the output, I would be more than happy to remove the printf.

The only way I have so far got it to work is to check if the object has "errno" but this seems like a "hacky" way to do it.

```
const winston = require('winston');
const {Loggly} = require('winston-loggly-bulk');
const tag = (process.env['HOSTNAME']) ? (process.env['HOSTNAME']) : 'localhost';
const {splat, combine, printf, colorize, timestamp, simple} = winston.format;
let alignColorsAndTime = combine(
    colorize({
        all:true
    }),
    timestamp({
        format:"YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS"
    }),
    printf(msg => {
        if (msg.errno !== undefined) {
            msg.message = JSON.stringify(msg)
        }
        return msg.level + msg.timestamp + msg.message;
    })
);

//Logging levels: error: 0, warn: 1, info: 2, verbose: 3, debug: 4, silly: 5
winston.add(new Loggly({
    token: [REMOVED],
    subdomain: [REMOVED],
    tags: [[REMOVED] + process.env['ENVIRONMENT'], tag],
    json: true,
    level : (process.env['LOG_LEVEL']) ? (process.env['LOG_LEVEL']) : 'debug'
}));
winston.add(new winston.transports.Console({
    format: alignColorsAndTime,
    level : 'debug',
}));


module.exports = winston;
```